# How to store by the second data in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, data-structures

I have data arriving at the rate of one item per second and need to store it in python 3.5. I need to be able to calculate the running total from the last 24 hours and also the totals for each day as the data arrives. Restarting the program should reset all of the stored data so there's no need for persistent storage.

I was planning on using pandas dataframes but they don't seem to be suited to appending data.

Is there a method of storing data indexed by time, allowing appending data one row at a time?

Comment: Have you tried using numpy arrays? They are faster than ordinary lists and can append data fast enough (in comparison to 1 items per sec)

Comment: I need some way of indexing the data by datetime so that I can work out the daily totals (and possibly some other time based searches later.) I guess I could have two numpy arrays, one with datetimes and one with values, but it feels a bit overcomplicated.

Comment: Please review what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic]. This is explicitly off-topic as (a) too broad, (b) likely asking us to find or recommend an off-site resource, and (c) primarily opinion-based. Any one of those is enough to make it off-topic.

Comment: @TheGribble Rather than going for 2 lists you can go for a list of tuples (pairs). In case you get only one entry per second strictly, you can use a fixed array of length 86400.